React native html to pdf with <embed><embed/>

const pdfFile = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert({
html:
    `<div class="pageBreak">
        // Other ui
        <embed class="term" type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,YourBase64EncodedPDFHere"/>
    </div>`,
fileName: subjectLine,
pageSize: 'Letter',
padding: 0,
base64: true })


The YourBase64EncodedPDFHere length is 212335.The content inside the embed tag will not be displayed in the final generated PDF. This only happens on real machines, not in emulators.
my iphone ios version is 17.4 ,my simulator ios version is 17.0
I wonder if this tag is not compatible with iOS 17
